# Ios .mobileconfig how to make it verified

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, configuration-profile

I am struggling with ios configuration profiles.
We need to apply some settings to all our company ios devices.

I've created .mobileconfig file using apple configurator tool. When I am trying to install profile via our webserver, the profile appears as Not Verified.

I found how to use openssl to sign it , the question is what certificate do I need to use as -signer key in command line ?

Do I need to use apple development certificate , or i need to issues special certificate via Verisign ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate you use as -signer can be obtained by making a certificate signing request (CRS) to a certificate authority (CA). You can buy commercial certificates from companies like VeriSign etc.

To create a CRS see the link below:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt

Optionally you can create a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL (which will have caveats however), see link below:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/